# iphone - preventing tabs to change in tab view controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I've having tab view controller in my MainWindow.xib file. It has 3 tabs. The view controllers for each tab is also assigned in XIB only.
I want to prevent tab 3 being displayed depending on some condition check.

I know that I've to implement the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

But how can I check if its third tab or not? So if its third tab, i'll return NO, else I'll return YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This should tell you the tab index
NSInteger tabIndex = [[tbController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

// Then it's easy
return tabIndex != 3;
```